# how to use .val()[0] for 2 digit numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im working on simple credit card script that when put specified 1 digit on input field it uses .change() to show correct card firm (Visa,Mastercard,Amex) from png picture by slightly altering the CSS, aswell with .val()[0] it only read from first value or digit.

**Js** :

```
$( "#ccnr" ).change(function() {
                var firstNumber = $('#ccnr').val()[0]; //Problem here
                if (firstNumber == 3) {
                 $("#ccnr").css("background-position", "225px 12%");
                } else if (firstNumber == 4) {
                    $("#ccnr").css("background-position", "225px -0.5%");
                } else if (firstNumber == 6) {
                    $("#ccnr").css("background-position", "225px 18%");
                } else if (firstNumber == 5) {
                    $("#ccnr").css("background-position", "225px 5.7%");
                } else {
                    $("#ccnr").css("background-position", "225px 87%");
                }
            });
```

**html**

```
<tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom:7px"><b><label style="font-size:13px"> Number:</label></b></td>
    <td style="padding-bottom:7px">

        <input name="ccnr" autocomplete="off" id="ccnr" style="background-image: url(https://image.prntscr.com/image/FBB6i2bDQMmUAKYKY2TFrg.png);background-position:225px 87%;background-repeat: no-repeat;height:22px;width:250px;margin-top:-5px;" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
```

How can i use two digit number for example like this?

JS :

```
$( "#ccnr" ).change(function() {
                var firstNumber = $('#ccnr').val()[0]; 
                if (firstNumber == 37) {   //Set to two digit
                 $("#ccnr").css("background-position", "225px 12%");
                } else if (firstNumber == 45) {
                    $("#ccnr").css("background-position", "225px -0.5%");
                } else if (firstNumber == 60) {
                    $("#ccnr").css("background-position", "225px 18%");
                } else if (firstNumber == 55) {
                    $("#ccnr").css("background-position", "225px 5.7%");
                } else {
                    $("#ccnr").css("background-position", "225px 87%");
                }
            });
```

It's not working.

Comment: You can try this on some editors.

Comment: The `[0]` is completely unnecessary -- just use `.val()`.  If the value is a string, `[0]` is just pulling the first character out of the string.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to extract first 2 character:

```
var firstNumber = $('#ccnr').val().substr(0,2);
```

with .substr(0,2) it's working.

Comment: Thank you for this! it works!
with .substr(0); works best!

Comment: However when i use only `.val()` without `[0]` , the purpose of this script drop down as the CSS style back to normal form when the value is  different from what i given to variable.
  E.x : 

`} else if (firstNumber == 45) {
                    $("#ccnr").css("background-position", "225px -0.5%"); `   
so like when put "453" , "451" or any 3 digit or above numbers, the CSS set to default.

Comment: Glad to hear it! If the answer is correct, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: the answer was helpful you can edit with this :

`var firstNumber = $('#ccnr').val().substr(0,2);`

or i;ll do it.